# The description of the Teacher badge is ambiguous

Tags: bug, badges, wording

Currently the [Teacher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1/teacher) badge's description is:

> Answer a question with score of 1 or more

This is ambiguous. It can either mean "answer a question and get a score of 1 [on your answer]" (the correct interpretation) or "answer a question which has a score of 1 or more" (i.e. the question is positively scored at the time of answering).

Could we change it to something a little clearer? Say, for example:

> First answer with score of 1 or more

This would bring it in line with the Student badge.

Comment: Your suggested wording seems potentially ambiguous too: it could be misinterpreted as saying that only the first answer to each question qualifies for that badge. (Compare e.g. with [Enlightened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened), which actually *does* have that requirement.) Still, I agree that the wording should probably be improved somehow.

Comment: "Answer score of 1 or more" and group it with Nice Answer, Good Answer

Comment: There is also an entry in the FAQ set: *[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?, Answer Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258)*

Answer (score 4):

I agree. The wording really actually means that answer a question in which the answer gets a score of 1 but it took me a while to understand the true meaning of the badge because the wording was so confusing. The summary should be straight-forward to allow users to immediately know how to get the badges.

Your summary should work nicely and I love to see a connection between Teacher and Student as well. Also, the Teacher badge's description seems to be able to be earned more than one time so the word "First" in the beginning should clarify the summary a little bit more.

Comment: Seems to be worse than that: awarded to having an answer that *momentarily* had a positive score.

Answer (score 3):

The same thing just happened to me. I'd propose the following wording:

> Post an answer with a score of 1 or more.